# Почему выдается ошибка?

Tags: php, mysql, webforms

Код вырван из контекста, но я думаю не имеет смысла копировать сюда всю программу.
Есть код PHP, который обрабатывает данные, введенные в форму:

```
<?php
 require_once "reg file/login.php";
 $connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
 if ($connection->connect_error) die("Сбой подключения к БД.");
//В if'е выдается ошибка из-за функции get_post()
    if (isset(get_post($connection, "delete")) && isset(get_post($connection, 
"delete")) { 

     $number = get_post($connection, "number");
     $query = "DELETE FROM `accounts` WHERE `number` = $number";
     $result = $connection->query($query);
     if (!$result) echo "Ошибка при удалении данных.<br>"; 
 }
 function get_post($connection, $var) {
    return $connection->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
 }
?>
```

Форма:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name = "delete" value="yes">
     <input type="hidden" name = "number" value="<?php echo $n?>">
     <input type="submit" value="Удалить запись">
    </form>
```

Выдает ошибку:
**Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in <имя файла> on line 6**
Если заменить get_post() на $_POST[...], то всё работает. Почему так? В чём проблема?

Comment: вы пытались прочитать текст ошибки и перевести его? вам там даже написано на что заменит вашу конструкцию можно.  либо сохранить результат в переменную сначала

Comment: @teran Да тексты эти это программисты пишут, пусть они и понимают.

Comment: @teran не пытался) Теперь всё ясно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо заменить функции `isset()` на `null !== get_post($connection, "delete")` и `null !==get_post($connection, "number")`.